# WMMA default cores

Tags: cuda, cublas, cuda-wmma

I'm running [nvidia's sample code](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/programming-tensor-cores-cuda-9). The Code can be found on [github](https://github.com/NVIDIA-developer-blog/code-samples/tree/master/posts/tensor-cores): 
I know from the [CUDA toolkit documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-GemmEx) that the code

> Allows the library to use Tensor Core operations whenever possible

by using `CUBLAS_TENSOR_OP_MATH`.

In the documentation I've found that `CUBLAS_DEFAULT_MATH` prevents the library from using Tensor Core operations, HOWEVER the sample code doesn't use that.

What is the default setting for WMMA? Will it be executed on CUDA cores or is there a POSSIBILTY that Tensor cores might support computing.

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#wmma -- I really don't understand what/why you are asking

Comment: I'm asking whether matrix multiplication will be done using CUDA or TENSOR cores by default.

Comment: In other words: what if I don't use neither CUBLAS_DEFAULT_MATH nor CUBLAS_TENSOR_OP_MATH. Will the Tensor cores be used?

Comment: wmma namespace is made to interact with tensorcore, so `wmma_example` will be done using tensorCore in all cases.
For `cublasGemmEx`, CUBLAS_DEFAULT_MATH is used by default so it will not try to use tensorcore if you do not set CUBLAS_TENSOR_OP_MATH.

Comment: What matrix multiplication? The WMMA code? That WMMA API only exists to provide access to the tensor cores. It won't compile or run on GPUs without the required hardware support

Comment: Ok, thanks. Maybe I did not form my question properly eariler. I was just trying to make sure that I'm comparing matrix multiplications done on CUDA cores to TENSOR cores.

Comment: Moreover, you can check if your kernel is using tensor core via [nvprof or nvvp](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/using-nsight-compute-nvprof-mixed-precision-deep-learning-models/)

Comment: You cannot use wmma instructions/intrinsics unless you compile for a GPU architecture that supports tensor core (you'll get a compile error).  You cannot disable or modify this behavior with any setting.  You cannot use wmma instructions/intrinsics to do anything on CUDA cores.   They only work on tensorcore.  The CUBLAS_ settings affect CUBLAS calls, not the use of wmma instructions/intrinsics.

Answer (score 1):

[wmma instructions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#wmma) can only use (ie. execute on) Tensor Core hardware.  They cannot execute on any other type of hardware.  For this reason, when compiling CUDA device code with wmma instructions, you must target an architecture (cc7.x, currently) that has Tensor Core hardware.  Furthermore, such code will only run correctly on a cc7.x device (currently).

The CUBLAS variables you refer to affect usage of the CUBLAS API.  They have no connection to wmma instructions that you code yourself.

Underneath the hood, the CUBLAS library has multiple code paths.  The CUBLAS variables you refer to may affect code path decisions that the CUBLAS library may make.  Some of those code paths may use wmma instructions or equivalent Tensor Core usage.  Other code paths may perform the same operation (at a high level, e.g. matrix-matrix multiply) without using wmma instructions.